# Loading Bootstrap in NW.js (node-webkit) app with pure npm build

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, node-webkit

I'm trying to build a simple desktop app with [NW.js](http://nwjs.io/). Inspired by some posts including [this one](https://medium.com/@housecor/why-i-left-gulp-and-grunt-for-npm-scripts-3d6853dd22b8#.vj55hmupw), I wanted to try a pure `npm` approach without any `bower`, `grunt`, or `gulp`.

So I go ahead and use `jquery` and `bootstrap` libraries installed as `npm` modules. When I'm injecting the modules in my app's javascript like this:

```
global.jQuery = $ = require("jquery");
var bootstrap = require("bootstrap");
```

I'm getting a `ReferenceError: document is not defined` from `bootstrap`. I can load `bootstrap` through the html document in the old-fashioned way though:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

I'm asking myself if it's a stupid idea to load bootstrap trough `require` in the script file? Basically, I don't need it there. It can be loaded via  a script tag in html. What are the best practices? I'm confused.

**Update. The solution**

Having taken the advice from @Kuf, I created a `build.js` script

```
var copyfiles = require('copyfiles');
copyfiles(["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js", "vendor/js"], true, function (err) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
});
copyfiles(["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css", "vendor/css"], true, function (err) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
});
```

triggered by a `prestart` hook:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "node build.js",
  "prestart": "npm run build"
}
```

which allows me to access `bootstrap` resources by convenient paths:

```
<link href="vendor/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error occurs because you are running the require without window context. Where are you running the include from? notice that for code running from `node-main`:

> window: ... is not available at the time the script is loaded, because
>   the script is executed before the DOM window load. ([source](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/node-main))

Even when importing the JS using require, you still need to include the css files.I don't think there is a 'clean' or out-of-the-box solution yet. Although what you are doing will definitely work, it will generate weird and not natural script path.

I would add a build [script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts):

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "node build.js"
  }
```

in package.json to copy bootstrap from node_modules into  '/dist/' to make the path cleaner.